# finding TRUE and FALSE summation using grepl function in r

Tags: r

I am searching for particular words within a text vector using `grepl`. My function ran very well but with several `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s in the output. I am looking for a way to sum the number of the `FALSE`s and `TRUE`s in my output.

Comment: Use `table` to do this

Comment: @dasurschn You should format your question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) next time.

Comment: as soon as you can (I think there's a minimum time of something like an hour for new users?), you can/are encouraged to post an answer based on @akrun's comment (unless they feel like doing it themselves in the meantime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear on @akrun response,

```
text_vector <- c("hello world", "world map", "travels", "world", "hllo wrld")

res <- grepl(pattern = "world", text_vector)

> table(res)
FALSE  TRUE 
    2     3 

> sum(res) # no. TRUE
[1] 3

> sum(!res) # no. TRUE
[1] 2
```